# Are eBay user tokens permanent (Fetch user token API)?

Tags: ebay-api

According to the [eBay docs](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Basics/Tokens-MultipleUsers.html): "With one-time setup complete, your application can respond to prospective users and get tokens for them." However, the article also mentions that the tokens expire after 48 hours. Does this mean that my users will have to re-login every 48 hours through my website to renew the token? If so, how is this a one-time setup?

**Update 1:** According to [this article](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Basics/Tokens-About.html), tokens expire after 18 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokens expire after 18 months. The call returns a `HardExpirationWarning` element 7 days before the token expires, at which point the user has to go through the consent process again. The token is associated with the session ID for 48 hours, before which the developer has to fetch the user's token and save it for future API calls.

Comment: Okay, can you explain how do you fetch user token with session ID, https://developer.ebay.com/my/api_test_tool?index=0&env=sandbox&api=trading&call=FetchToken&variation=xml after a few tests it says: "The end user has not completed Auth &amp; Auth sign in flow." Even though I went through sign in process..